# The Golden ellipse

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, golden-ratio

About a year ago I discovered the golden ellipse, which has many interesting properties

It is an ellipse, the ratio between its large diameter and the distance between the two foci is equal to $φ$

$φ=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$

[image]

First, the ratio between the large diameter and the small diameter is equal to the square root of the golden ratio

[image]

$\frac{a}{b}=\sqrt{φ}$

Secondly, the foci of the golden ellipse are located in the middle of two opposite sides of the square centered at the center of the ellipse, whose vertices belong to the ellipse.

[image]

Thirdly, the ratio between the small diameter and the side of the square is equal to the square root of the golden ratio

Fourth, the line connecting the focus of a golden ellipse and its astigmatic peak is perpendicular to the line connecting that astigmatic peak and the peak.
The focal point farthest from the taken focus

[image]

Fifthly, if a square is drawn whose sides touch a golden ellipse, the tangent points will form the vertices of a golden rectangle.

[image]

Sixthly, if we determine its four points of intersection with the accompanying hyperbola, we will form a rectangle with the ratio between its dimensions equal $\sqrt{2}$

[image]

My question is, can the golden ellipse be considered a new exclusive discovery or is it already known?

Please cite any sources that speak about it

Comment: i dont think  "golden" figures are considered exclusive discoveries they just happen to have nice algebraic properties i could be wrong tho  but i havent seen it treated specially in any books or such

Comment: The 2022 note ["Properties of an ellipse whose eccentricity is $1/\phi$" (PDF link via himmlisch.com)](http://himmlisch.com/fibonacci_ellipse.pdf), by Roy Dvorak, discusses this ellipse, dubbed the "Fibonacci ellipse" ... maybe. It mentions the ellipse with eccentricity $1/\phi$, at least in the beginning, but also discusses ellipses with Fibonacci numbers for major and minor axes. It's hard to know how seriously to take the work, since it has multiple instances of writing "eclipse" for "ellipse" (also "ration" for "ratio", etc). I stopped reading after the first couple of paragraphs.

Comment: Yes, it's the same ellipse I'm talking about, it seems he wasn't interested in finding the geometric properties that it has blue

Comment: @زكرياحسناوي: *"it seems he wasn't interested in finding the geometric properties that it has"* Okay. ... In any case, I suspect this ellipse and its properties have been discussed in the literature somewhere; people have been fascinated by both conic sections and the Golden Ratio for a good long while. (As always, that someone has gotten to a result before us doesn't diminish the accomplishment of discovering it anew.) A meticulous web search for "golden eccentricity" or related terms may prove fruitful.

Comment: Thank you @blue

Comment: It appears that the sides of the triangle $∆A'FB$ form a geometric sequence whose basis is $\sqrt{φ}$